# Using MVVM Communitytoolkit to change button foreground or background

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. I'm starting to build a sample project based on an WinForm design.
The part I'm stuck on is setting a RadioButton Foreground and/or Background. I was told and given instruction to use "Styles" to do this.
XAML looks like this for the Window.Resources:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GroupToggleStyle" TargetType="RadioButton" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsErrorProcess, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                         Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

My XAML code for the radio button:

```xml
<RadioButton GroupName="btnErrorLog"
             Command="{Binding OpenError}"
             Content="{Binding ErrorText}"
             Width="80"
             IsEnabled="{Binding IsProcessingData}"
             Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Style="{StaticResource GroupToggleStyle}" />
```

This will change the text/content of the RadioButton when clicked to "RED". However I'm tring to get the button foreground (at this time) to change to "Red" only when public property "IsErrorProcess" changes to "true".
I believe I have the binding correct on both "style" and "radiobutton".

My problem is this. When I set IsErrorProcess to true I cannot figure out how to set the color for the foreground to red.

My MainWindowViewModel.cs code: (I had to remove real customer data files)

```cs
    using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
    using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
    using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging;
    using ImporterMessaging;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using Wpsi.CorrelDataImporter;


    namespace CorelImporter
    {
        public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableRecipient
        {
        #region Variables/Fields
        private string _importFileName = string.Empty;
        private int _digitLength;
        private string _filterString = string.Empty;
        private List<CorrelUserRecord> _correlUserData = new List<CorrelUserRecord>();
        private List<string> _afterData = new List<string>();
        private List<string> _beforeData = new List<string>();
        private ObservableObject _count;
        private string _processingText;
        private bool _isProcessingData;
        private string _statusMessage;
                private string _errorText;
                private bool _isErrorProcess;
        public Brush btnErrorColor;
        #endregion

        #region RelayCommands
        public AsyncRelayCommand ProcessData { get; set; }
        public AsyncRelayCommand OpenError { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public string ImportFileName
        {
            get => _importFileName;
            set
            {
                if (_importFileName == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _importFileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImportFileName));
            }
        }
        public string FilterString
        {
            get => _filterString;
            set
            {
                if (_filterString == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _filterString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilterString));
            }
        }
        public List<CorrelUserRecord> CorrelUserData
        {
            get => _correlUserData;
            set
            {
                if (_correlUserData == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _correlUserData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CorrelUserData));
            }
        }
        public List<string> AfterData
        {
            get => _afterData;
            set
            {
                if (_afterData == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _afterData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AfterData));
            }
        }
        public List<string> BeforeData
        {
            get => _beforeData;
            set
            {
                if (_beforeData == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _beforeData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BeforeData));
            }
        }
        public int DigitLength
        {
            get => _digitLength;
            set
            {
                if (_digitLength == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _digitLength = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DigitLength));
            }
        }
        public ObservableObject Count
        {
            get => _count;
            set
            {
                if (_count == value)
                    return;
                _count = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Count));

            }
        }
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get => Globals.IsChecked;
            set
            {
                if (Globals.IsChecked == value)
                    return;
                Globals.IsChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
            }
        }
        public bool IsProcessingData
        {
            get => _isProcessingData;
            set
            {
                if (_isProcessingData == value)
                    return;
                _isProcessingData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsProcessingData));
            }
        }
        public string ProcessingText
        {
            get => _processingText;
            set
            {
                if (_processingText== value)
                    return;
                _processingText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProcessingText));
            }
        }
        public string StatusMessage
        {
            get => _statusMessage;
            set
            {
                if (_statusMessage == value)
                    return;
                _statusMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StatusMessage));
            }
        }
        public string ErrorText
        {
            get => _errorText;
            set
            {
                if (_errorText == value)
                    return;
                _errorText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ErrorText));
            }
        }
        public bool IsErrorProcess
        {
            get => _isErrorProcess;
            set
            {
                if (_isErrorProcess == value)
                    return;
                _isErrorProcess = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsErrorProcess));
                btnErrorColor = Brushes.Red;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(btnErrorColor));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ImportFileName = Path.Combine(CorrelDataImporter.ImportExportPath, @"");
            DigitLength = 11;
            FilterString = "+1214648";
            AfterData.Add("AFTER NOT DATA LOADED");
            BeforeData.Add("BEFORE NOT DATA LOADED");
            ProcessingText = "Click To Process";
            ErrorText = "Error Log";
            IsProcessingData = true;
            IsErrorProcess = true;
            StatusMessage = string.Empty;
            //Count = 0.ToString();

            ProcessData = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnProcessDataExecute, () => true);
            OpenError = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnOpenErrorExecute, () => true);

            // Register a message in some module
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<CorrelImporterStatusMessages>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                // Handle the message here, with r being the recipient and m being the
                // input message. Using the recipient passed as input makes it so that
                // the lambda expression doesn't capture "this", improving performance.
                UpdateStatusMessage(m.Value);
            });
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<UpdateBeforeDataList>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                // Handle the message here, with r being the recipient and m being the
                // input message. Using the recipient passed as input makes it so that
                // the lambda expression doesn't capture "this", improving performance.
                UpdateBeforeList(m.Value);
            });
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<UpdateAfterDataList>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                // Handle the message here, with r being the recipient and m being the
                // input message. Using the recipient passed as input makes it so that
                // the lambda expression doesn't capture "this", improving performance.
                UpdateAfterList(m.Value);
            });
            //WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<ErrorButtonColor>(this, (r, m) =>
            //{
            //  // Handle the message here, with r being the recipient and m being the
            //  // input message. Using the recipient passed as input makes it so that
            //  // the lambda expression doesn't capture "this", improving performance.
            //  IsErrorProcess(m.Value);
            //});
        }
        private void UpdateBeforeList(List<string> value)
        {
            BeforeData = value;
        }
        private void UpdateAfterList(List<string> value)
        {
            AfterData = value;
        }
        private void UpdateStatusMessage(string statusMessage)
        {
            StatusMessage = statusMessage;
        }
        //private void ErrorButtonColor(System.Drawing.Color value)
        //{
        //  IsErrorProcess.f = Color.Red;
        //}
        private async Task OnProcessDataExecute()
        {
            if (Globals.IsChecked == true)
            {
                string sDeleteFile = $"{Globals.sAPPPath}\\{Globals.sApplicationName}" + ".log";
                if (File.Exists(sDeleteFile))
                    File.Delete(sDeleteFile);
                
                IsChecked = false;
            }

            IsProcessingData = false;
            ProcessingText = "Processing Data...";

            await LoadCorrelData();

            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new CorrelImporterStatusMessages($"Process completed."));

            IsProcessingData = true;
            ProcessingText = "Click To Process";

            btnErrorColor = Brushes.Black;
            if (Globals.bErrorOn == true)
            {
                IsErrorProcess = true;
                btnErrorColor = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }

        private async Task OnOpenErrorExecute()
        {
            if(Globals.bErrorOn == true) 
            {
                IsErrorProcess= true;
                Process myProcess = new Process();
                string sGet = $"{Globals.sAPPPath}\\{Globals.sApplicationName}" + ".log";
                Process.Start("notepad.exe", sGet);

            }
        }
        public async Task LoadCorrelData()
        {
                    CorrelUserData = await CorrelDataImporter.ProcessCorrelData(Path.Combine(CorrelDataImporter.ImportExportPath, @""));

            //This program is much like Command Project but in WPF
            await CorrelDataImporter.ProcessAfterList(CorrelUserData, FilterString, DigitLength);
        }
    }
}
```

Using "CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging.Messages". It was also suggested I could use this method to call the radio button style changed but I can't work it out. Real don't know what I'm doing without a working sample. **I'm still not sure when "Styles" are needed and not.** help here would be appreciated as well.

A working solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` because `Self` indicates the `RadioButton` in this case, and `IsErrorProcess` is in your ViewModel not in the `RadioButton`.

This is the minimal code that works (updates the `RadioButton`'s `Foreground`) for me.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding IsErrorProcess}"
                Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button
        Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
        Content="Test" />
    <RadioButton Content="{Binding ErrorText}" />
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isErrorProcess;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string? errorText;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Test()
    {
        IsErrorProcess = IsErrorProcess is false;
        ErrorText = IsErrorProcess is true
            ? "Error text"
            : string.Empty;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: I took liberties to add you code to mine. I find that once the program kicks off the Foreground "Error Log" is in red. I would like to have the radio button Foreground color be black and only change to red when I set it as in the code line:   "if (Globals.bErrorOn == true)
            {
                IsErrorProcess = true;
                btnErrorColor = Brushes.Red;
            }"

Comment: My example code just switch the `Foreground` from *Blue* to *Red*, vice versa, triggered by the **IsErrorProcess**. Did you set the `Foreground` inside the `Style`? The line where I set *Blue* in my code.

Comment: Ok, I see what I was doing wrong. In my "public MainWindowViewModel()" I set "IsErrorProcess" to true.  With "IsErrorProcess" set to false the radio button text/content is now blue. When the "Global.bErrorOn" is checked the "IsErrorProcess = IsErrorProcess is false;" invokes the Foreground to change.

Comment: Thank you very much I was not understanding what was happening. Are there more controls like button/radio button that require a "Style" to set color or other properties control properties?

Comment: If you just need to set colors, like `Foreground` or `Background`, you don't need a `Style`.