C# WPF: Changing the button Context="{Binding Text}" when pressed
New to WPF programming I'm coming from WinForms. I have two working WinForms project/solutions I want to convert them to WPF. I managed to bull my way through the XMAL and MainWindowViewModel but hit a wall.
Checked the internet for working code to get the "Button" text to change when pressed.
My issue is that I can't change the Text of the Button's Context to something different.
I would like to change the button text from current to "Running..." when press then once the command completes change back to previous.
My XAML:
<Window x:Class="XPR_AppBuilderSuiteWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XPR_AppBuilderSuiteWpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="XPR-AppBuilder Suite WPF Version" Height="680" Width="820">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GroupToggleStyle" TargetType="RadioButton" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsErrorProcess}" 
                      Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="Beige">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="260"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Height="295" Margin="0,0,0,4">
            <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" Header="AB XML Reader" Width="778" Height="120" Margin="10,-160,10,14">
                <StackPanel Height="251">
                    <Button x:Name="btnSeletXMLFile" Content="{Binding sSelectXMLFile}" Command="{Binding btnSelectXMLFile}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            Margin="5,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="76"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnFindTags" Content="{Binding sFindTags}" Command="{Binding btnFindTags}" Margin="-452,-20,0,0" Height="20" Width="72"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnSelectFolder" Content="{Binding sSelectFolder}" Command="{Binding btnSelectFolder}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            Margin="245,-19,0,25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="72"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkBCallflowXML" Content="Run Callflow XML" IsChecked="{Binding IschkBCallflowXML}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsProcessingData}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,-14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15" Width="113"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkBWorkspaceXML" Content="Run Worksapce XML" IsChecked="{Binding IschkBWorkspaceXML}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsProcessingData}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="126,-14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15" Width="130"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkBAppXML" Content="Run Application XML" IsChecked="{Binding IschkBAppXML}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsProcessingData}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="268,-14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15" Width="131"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkBVariablesXML" Content="Run Variables XML" IsChecked="{Binding IschkBVariablesXML}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsProcessingData}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="407,-14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15" Width="125"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkBDontAddFilename" Content="Don't add file name" IsChecked="{Binding IschkBDontAddFilename}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsProcessingData}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="534,-14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Filter exclusion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtBFilter" Text="{Binding txtBFilter}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,-20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <Label x:Name="label2" Content="Result window:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-786,137,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBResult" Text="{Binding txtBResult}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-777,164,19,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="762" Height="50"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="lblStatus" Content="Status:" Margin="20,5,720,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBStatus" Text="{Binding txtBStatus}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="13,33,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="777"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightSkyBlue" Grid.Row="2">
            <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox2" Header="AB Deployed Reader"  Width="778" Height="200" Margin="10,-20,10,14">
                <StackPanel >
                    <Label x:Name="lbABDeployed" Content="{Binding lblABDeployed}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="125" Width="743"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnStartABDeployedReader" Content="{Binding sStart}" Command="{Binding btnStartABDeployedReader}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,13,0,15" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="50"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnOpenOutput" Command="{Binding btnOpenOutput}" Content="Open output file" Height="20" Width="100" Margin="-502,-35,0,15" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkBSingle" Content="Single application configuration" IsChecked="{Binding IschkBSingle}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsProcessingData}" Margin="196,-33,0,0" Width="198" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="24"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightCyan" Grid.Row="3">
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkBClearLog" Content="Clear error log" IsChecked="{Binding IschkBClearLog}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsProcessingData}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="btnErrorLog" Command="{Binding btnErrorLog}" Content="{Binding ErrorText}" Width="80"
             Margin="32,-25,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource GroupToggleStyle}" Height="20" IsEnabled="{Binding IsError}"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblVersion" Content="{Binding lblVersion}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-210,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <!--<Button x:Name="btnError" Content="Error Log" Command="{Binding btnErrorLog}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-92,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="50"/>-->
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>

My MainWindowViewModel: (no ViewModel created not fully enveloped in MVVM yet, using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm). Partial code to reduce the amount of data.
namespace XPR_AppBuilderSuiteWpf
{
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableRecipient
    {
        #region Variables/Fields
        private string _txtBFilter;
        private string _txtBResult;
        private string _txtBStatus;
        private string _lblVersion;
        private string _lblABDeployed;
        private bool _ischkBCallflowXML;
        private bool _ischkBWorkspaceXML;
        private bool _ischkBAppXML;
        private bool _ischkBVariablesXML;
        private bool _ischkBDontAddFilename;
        private bool _ischkBSingle;
        private bool _ischkBClearLog;
        private bool _isError;//enables the button to be clicked on else it is not enabled.
        private bool _isErrorProcess;//use to set the error button color.
        private bool _isProcessingData;//to enable or disable the checkboxes, buttons or other controls
        private string _sSelectXMLFile = string.Empty;
        private string _sFindTags = string.Empty;
        private string _sSelectFolder = string.Empty;
        private string _sStart = string.Empty;

        #endregion
        #region RelayCommands
        //aka buttons or "Commands={Binding...}"
        public AsyncRelayCommand btnSelectXMLFile { get; set; }
        public AsyncRelayCommand btnFindTags { get; set; }
        public AsyncRelayCommand btnSelectFolder { get; set; }
        public AsyncRelayCommand btnStartABDeployedReader { get; set; }
        public AsyncRelayCommand btnOpenOutput { get; set; }
        public AsyncRelayCommand btnErrorLog { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region Properties
        //aka textboxes, checkboxes, listboxes etc
        public bool IschkBCallflowXML
        {
            get => _ischkBCallflowXML;
            set
            {
                if (_ischkBCallflowXML == value)
                    return;
                _ischkBCallflowXML = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IschkBCallflowXML));
            }
        }
        public bool IschkBWorkspaceXML
        {
            get => _ischkBWorkspaceXML;
            set
            {
                if (_ischkBWorkspaceXML == value)
                    return;
                _ischkBWorkspaceXML = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IschkBWorkspaceXML));
            }
        }
        public bool IschkBAppXML
        {
            get => _ischkBAppXML;
            set
            {
                if (_ischkBAppXML == value)
                    return;
                _ischkBAppXML = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IschkBAppXML));
            }
        }
        public bool IschkBVariablesXML
        {
            get => _ischkBVariablesXML;
            set
            {
                if (_ischkBVariablesXML == value)
                    return;
                _ischkBVariablesXML = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IschkBVariablesXML));
            }
        }
        public bool IschkBDontAddFilename
        {
            get => _ischkBDontAddFilename;
            set
            {
                if (_ischkBDontAddFilename == value)
                    return;
                _ischkBDontAddFilename = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IschkBDontAddFilename));
            }
        }
        public string txtBFilter
        {
            get => _txtBFilter;
            set
            {
                if (_txtBFilter == value)
                    return;
                _txtBFilter = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(txtBFilter));
            }
        }
        public string txtBResult
        {
            get => _txtBResult;
            set
            {
                if (_txtBResult == value)
                    return;
                _txtBResult = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(txtBResult));
            }
        }
        public string txtBStatus
        {
            get => _txtBStatus;
            set
            {
                if (_txtBStatus == value)
                    return;
                _txtBStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(txtBStatus));
            }
        }
        public string lblABDeployed
        {
            get => _lblABDeployed;
            set
            {
                if (_lblABDeployed == value)
                    return;
                _lblABDeployed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(lblABDeployed));
            }
        }
        public bool IschkBSingle
        {
            get => _ischkBSingle;
            set
            {
                if (_ischkBSingle == value)
                    return;
                _ischkBSingle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IschkBSingle));
            }
        }
        public bool IschkBClearLog
        {
            get => _ischkBClearLog;
            set
            {
                if (_ischkBClearLog == value)
                    return;
                _ischkBClearLog = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IschkBClearLog));
            }
        }
        public bool IsProcessingData
        {
            get => _isProcessingData;
            set
            {
                if (_isProcessingData == value)
                    return;
                _isProcessingData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsProcessingData));
            }
        }
        public string lblVersion
        {
            get => _lblVersion;
            set
            {
                if (_lblVersion == value)
                    return;
                _lblVersion = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(lblVersion));
            }
        }
        public bool IsError
        {
            get => _isError;
            set
            {
                if (_isError == value)
                    return;
                _isError = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsError));
            }
        }
        public bool IsErrorProcess
        {
            get => _isErrorProcess;
            set
            {
                if (_isErrorProcess == value)
                    return;
                _isErrorProcess = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsErrorProcess));
            }
        }
        public string sSelectXMLFile
        {
            get => _sSelectXMLFile;
            set
            {
                if (_sSelectXMLFile == value)
                    return;
                _sSelectXMLFile = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(sSelectXMLFile));
            }
        }
        public string sFindTags
        {
            get => _sFindTags;
            set
            {
                if (_sFindTags == value)
                    return;
                _sFindTags = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(sFindTags));
            }
        }
        public string sSelectFolder
        {
            get => _sSelectFolder;
            set
            {
                if (_sSelectFolder == value)
                    return;
                _sFindTags = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(sSelectFolder));
            }
        }
        public string sStart
        {
            get => _sStart;
            set
            {
                if (_sStart == value)
                    return;
                _sFindTags = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(sStart));
            }
        }

        //End of declarations.

        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76871709/using-mvvm-communitytoolkit-to-change-button-foreground-or-background
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string? errorText;
        #endregion
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            txtBFilter = string.Empty;
            txtBResult = string.Empty;
            txtBStatus = string.Empty;
            lblVersion = string.Empty;
            lblABDeployed = string.Empty;
            ErrorText = "Error Log";
            IsError = false;
            IsProcessingData = true;//to enable or disable the checkboxes, buttons or other controls
            _sSelectXMLFile = "Select a XML";
            _sFindTags = "Find Tags";
            _sSelectFolder = "Select Folder";
            _sStart = "Start";

            string sTemp = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName;
            Globals.sApplicationName = sTemp.Substring(0, sTemp.IndexOf(","));
            Globals.sEFApplicationName = sTemp.Substring(0, sTemp.IndexOf(","));
            string[] aSplit = sTemp.Split(',');
            lblVersion = "Version: " + aSplit[0] + " " + aSplit[1];

            #region Button initialization
            btnSelectXMLFile = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnbtnSelectXMLFileExecute, () => true);
            btnFindTags = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnbtnFindTagsExecute, () => true);
            btnSelectFolder = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnbtnSelectFolderExecute, () => true);
            btnOpenOutput = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnbtnOpenOutputExecute, () => true);
            btnStartABDeployedReader = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnbtnStartABDeployedReaderExecute, () => true);
            btnErrorLog = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnbtnErrorLogExecute, () => true);

            lblABDeployed = "This program will read an Xpressions correl or  full export file.\n\r" +
                "Then create an Excel workbook in the folder the DB was specified.\n\r" +
                "All header values/names are those of AppBuilder as seen when deployed and written to the correl.";

            // Register a message in some module
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<StatusMessages>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                // Handle the message here, with r being the recipient and m being the
                // input message. Using the recipient passed as input makes it so that
                // the lambda expression doesn't capture "this", improving performance.
                UpdateStatusMessage(m.Value);
            });
            #endregion
        }
        private async Task OnbtnSelectXMLFileExecute()
        {
            if (IschkBClearLog == true)
                ClearErrorLog();

            string sHold = _sSelectXMLFile, sResult = string.Empty;
            _sSelectXMLFile = "Running...";

            OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFile.Multiselect = true;
            openFile.Title = "Select Application Builder XML file(s)"; //!!sets the dialog box title!!
            openFile.FileName = null;
            openFile.DefaultExt = "xml";
            openFile.Filter = "AppBuilder (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true)//if not true then it is cancel so skip
            {
                WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new StatusMessages($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} - Starting XML file processing."));
                ErrorFile.WriteError("======SelectXMLFile=====", "", 0);
                IsErrorProcess = false;

                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    sResult = ReadABXMLTasks.SeletXMLFileTask(IschkBDontAddFilename, openFile, IschkBCallflowXML, IschkBAppXML, IschkBVariablesXML,
                        IschkBWorkspaceXML);
                });

                //Work on this button click does not work
                if (Globals.bErrorOn == true)
                {
                    IsErrorProcess = IsErrorProcess is true;
                    IsError = true;
                }
            }
            _sSelectXMLFile = sHold;
            txtBResult = sResult;
        }

I hope this is enough code. Again I'm new to WPF. Showing code for button"btnSelectXMLFile". I hope to incorporate your assistance to the other buttons then to future project.

"Context" or "Content"?

"I hope this is enough code" - it is far too much. Please post the relevant parts of your code, not all of it.

Your problem is that you change the field in OnbtnSelectXMLFileExecute()
_sSelectXMLFile = "Running...";

Instead of the Property
sSelectXMLFile = "Running...";

This prevents the NotifyPropertyChanged Event from getting fired. And without the event getting fired the UI is not updated.

Thank you, I thought I did that already.
